# Cannot click on returned object from jquery selection

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, xpath

Using dev tools in chrome (tested with firefox as well), I crafted xpath for an element; when hovering over returned value $x(xpath), the element is highlighted.

But 'click' is not possible on the element;
Returns "Uncought TypeError: $x(..).click" is not a function.
The returned object by selector, has instead 'onclick', 'focus', 'className' etc methods. But not click;

The element is 'svg' type

Comment: This won't help; You need to show some code to get the answers.

Comment: Share the code you have tried, URL(if not possible, share the HTML) and the complete error message.

Comment: share the HTML code, for that svg element. also use @ to reply.

Answer (score 0):

click is not possible because it returns multiple element. try unique locator.